# Catch bad lines in csv file using pandas read_csv

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I am using pandas read_csv to read a 140k lines csv file. The format of the file is as follows:

```
"HEAD1", "HEAD2", "HEAD3"
"line1-1", "line1-2", "line1-3"
"line2-1", "line2-2", "line2-3"
```

There are some invalid lines as follows:

```
"line"3-1", "line3-2",, "li"ne3-4"
```

How can I catch and print out the invalid lines? Is it possible to do so using the read_csv function or I need to use csv.reader and check each line using a regular expression? If so, can somebody help me build a regular expression? I came up with the following, but it does not work

```
^".+\",?"?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try error_bad_lines=False when reading in the file?

Comment: @Gayatri, I did. It tells me line numbers. There is nothing wrong with that line. I dont know how to interpret the line numbers with that option turned on. The misplaced quotes are in other lines. I also looked at the lines before and after the like number raises in the error message. Same thing. Nothing wrong with those lines.

Comment: This works for my file format: (^"[^"]*")(,"[^"]*")*$